# Spring Web Unit test - How to get Database to a known state?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, spring, unit-testing

As the title says, I want to get my database to a "known state" to apply unit test. I can drop - recreate my database every time before running unit test, but is there any better way?

My web-application currently works with Spring context & Hibernate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest you use a tool called [DBUnit](http://www.dbunit.org) - which is designed to do exactly what you're looking for. There are loads of examples on the web of using it with Spring & Hibernate.

To load the data:

```
@Before
public void onSetUpInTransaction() throws Exception {
    Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
    try {
        IDatabaseConnection connection = new DatabaseConnection(conn);
        DatabaseConfig config = connection.getConfig();
        config.setProperty(DatabaseConfig.PROPERTY_DATATYPE_FACTORY,
                new HsqldbDataTypeFactory());
                    DataFileLoader loader = new FlatXmlDataFileLoader();
            IDataSet ds = loader.load(TEST_DATA_FILE_CLUB);
                    DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute(connection,ds);
            } finally {
        DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(conn, dataSource);
    }
}
```

This will take the XML file referenced in the TEST_DATA_FILE_CLUB string and load it into a clean in-memory copy of the database.

To clean down, simply have another method, annotated with @After, and use the DELETE_ALL database operation instead.

Assuming you're using JUnit, placing these methods in your test class, or in a superclass that test classes can extend, will allow you to set up the database exactly as you wish for each individual test, speedily.

The XML files to load are simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>
    <competition competitionId="1" competitionName="Competition 1"
        senior="1" junior="0"/>
</dataset>
```

will load an row into the competition table, with column values as specified. The senior & junior columns are booleans.

Comment: I have known about DBUnit somewhere before.. but I don't know  if it worth that much to learn a whole new framework. DBUnit seems too big to me

Comment: It's really not that hard - I use an in-memory database for my tests, so they're fast, and I simply reload the d/b to a clean state for each test. I'll add some code to my answer above

Comment: Thanks, I have successfully setup the in-memory database, but feels it a bit unclear how to set up DBUnit. Would you mind pointing me some resource?

Comment: All you need to do is ensure DBUnit is available on your classpath, then use the code listed above to load xml versions of your tables. These are very simple xml files (see structure in the main answer, edited now). Have a look at http://www.theserverside.com/news/1363748/Manage-test-data-for-integration-tests-using-Spring-and-DBunit - it has a lot of good stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing some kind of integration tests, then try to desing the tests so that each of them works no matter if an other one fails.

Then you need to setup the database only once (before the first test)

Btw: I strongly recommend to use different database (one for development) and one that is only used for the tests.

More technical details:
* if you use an inmemmory db for small and medium tests you can use spring jdbc support

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="H2" >
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:init.sql" />       
</jdbc:embedded-database>
```

- for real (big) integration tests, you could use the maven [sql-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/sql-maven-plugin/)

Comment: sorry if this is a dump question, but how to easily switch among databases? I currently config a JVM settings variable to change according the environment, but it requires me to re-set it every time I run the test.

Comment: That strongly depends on your setup. I personaly use JNDI. I have a deveopment server (on tomcat in my eclise) here the JNDI source points to one DB, and an other to run the integration tests direcly in eclipse (to develop the tests). Then I have an 3. tomcat that is configured through maven where the JNDI source points to an 3. DB. -- So I have different tomcat instances, each using the same JNDI name for the DB connection, but the connection points to different DBs

Comment: it sounds complicated. I have only one Tomcat integrated with Eclipse as my development server. Do you know any document about how to set up the environment like that?

Comment: No I do not know any specific for that setup.  For the maven Part I used maven cargo: http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin

Comment: thanks for the information. I'll try it out and let you know later. :)